# How to delete geth? How to update geth?

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to uninstall my geth, but I can't. How could I do it

Also, if I'd like to update my geth version, how could I do it?

**Edit** (added info according to the comment of @Ismael)
I'm using Ubuntu 16. I installed it from PPA, executing these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum
```

Comment: Which OS are you using? How did you installed geth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upgrade your client geth with normal debian/ubuntu commands

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To uninstall

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ethereum
```

To remove the ubuntu ppa (only do this after you have removed ethereum package)

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ethereum/ethereum
```

If you have run geth then you probably have $HOME/.ethereum and $HOME/.ethash directories with your keystore and blockchain data. If you used the wallet probably you want to make a backup of $HOME/.ethereum/keystore. If you no longer want to use ethereum in that machine you can remove both directories.

Answer (score 5):

You can run the following Commands to Completely Remove geth and related stuff. Run These With Caution, They have sensitive data in them.

```
$ sudo apt remove ethereum --purge        # Remove All Apps Related to ethereum
$ sudo apt autoremove                      # Uninstall dependencies
$ rm -rf ~/.ethereum                       # Remove Blockchain Data and Keystores
$ rm -rf ~/.ethash                         # Just a Bi-Product of Ethereum Mining
$ rm -rf ~/.clef                           # Account Management Tool and data
$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ethereum/ethereum  # Repository
```

If you want to update geth, You can run
`sudo apt install ethereum`

It will update ethereum to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Doing `sudo apt-get remove ethereum` didn't worked for me. I did

```
sudo apt-get remove geth
sudo apt-get remove clef
sudo apt autoremove // This will remove other dep. like abigen, evm, devp2p etc.
```